# Understanding Observable: not updating subscriber for an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, reactive-programming

I am trying to wrap my head around observables. I know when a value changes in observer, observable notify all its subscriber that something has changed. I am not sure why below code doesn't work. my understading is that once i add another element in array, subscriber should log new value or maybe log all values.

can someone please explain why is that?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

var numbers = [5, 1, 2, 7, 10];
// let source = Observable.from(numbers);
let source = Observable.create(observer => {
    for (let n of numbers)
        observer.next(n);

    observer.complete();

});

source.subscribe(
    value => console.log(`value is ${value}`),
    error => console.log(`error is ${error}`),
    () => console.log(`completed!`)
);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("pushing new value");
    numbers.push(33);
}, 3000);
```

I tried commenting observer.complete() as I thought that might be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observable from operator ( which is similar to the observable you've created )  does not 'listen' the array for it's onPush event ( no array has one in the default implementation ). The values you will get from the stream will be the one inside the array just before the subscribe call. The observable per se is just a function, it will just "copy" those values and emit them one by one, your array does not know how to "push" values to the stream. In the reactive world, everithing is a stream, most of the values you would store inside an array are stored in a stream of those values.

Comment: so you mean to say we cannot replicate array as stream? we will have to use Subject instead of Observable?

Comment: You can replicate a stream of values from an array, however there is no way for an array to push values to an existing observable. Observable emit new values by calling a next function. You can "send" your array to a subject next function and all its subscribers/operators will have those values pushed down the stream